# Compare igraph cluster membership across multiple iterations

Tags: r, igraph

This question builds on the example of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321028/what-is-the-reason-for-bizarre-r-igraph-spinglass-result-after-several-iteration). 
The aforementioned example shared this code for storing communities lists after multiple iterations of a given clustering algorithm. For instance, for 100 iterations:

```
communities <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
  set.seed(3+i)
  communities [[i]] <- cluster_spinglass(graph_obj)
}
```

Using igraph, if I run multiple iterations of a clustering method that has some sort of randomness to it (e.g. spinglass), I will obtain slightly different results at each time. Consequently, at each run, I might end up with a different number of clusters, and a different set of nodes within each cluster. Is there a way to keep track of how often certain nodes end up in the same clusters, across multiple iterations? The rationale would be to find out if, for instance, in 100 iterations, a certain node A was placed 90 times in the same cluster with node B, and 10 times elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be one number for each pair of nodes, so it seems
natural to keep track of this in a vcount x vcount matrix.

First, some sample data.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(13, 0.2)
```

Initialize a matrix to all zeros and then add one to the (i,j)
element each time that nodes i and j are in the same community.

```
COMM = matrix(0, nrow=vcount(g), ncol=vcount(g)) 
for(i in 1:100){
    set.seed(3+i)
    CS = cluster_spinglass(g)
    for(m in 1:max(CS$membership)) {
        Group = which(CS$membership==m)
        COMM[Group, Group] = COMM[Group, Group] +1
    }
}
COMM
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]  100    0    0   98    0    0    0    0    0     0   100     0   100
 [2,]    0  100    0    0   99    0   91   99    0     0     0    99     0
 [3,]    0    0  100    0    0  100    0    0  100   100     0     0     0
 [4,]   98    0    0  100    0    0    0    0    0     0    98     0    98
 [5,]    0   99    0    0  100    0   92  100    0     0     0   100     0
 [6,]    0    0  100    0    0  100    0    0  100   100     0     0     0
 [7,]    0   91    0    0   92    0  100   92    0     0     0    92     0
 [8,]    0   99    0    0  100    0   92  100    0     0     0   100     0
 [9,]    0    0  100    0    0  100    0    0  100   100     0     0     0
[10,]    0    0  100    0    0  100    0    0  100   100     0     0     0
[11,]  100    0    0   98    0    0    0    0    0     0   100     0   100
[12,]    0   99    0    0  100    0   92  100    0     0     0   100     0
[13,]  100    0    0   98    0    0    0    0    0     0   100     0   100
```

Now you can see that node 1 and 4 are in the same community 98 times out of 100,
but nodes 2 and 7 are only in the same community 91 times out of 100.
(Usually, there were 3 communities but sometimes there were 4. For example, when i=60,
we got 4 communities.)